# Convert image files (png, svg, bitmap, etc.) to ttf(True Typeface) through code

Tags: java, android, truetype

Looking for experience not a complete solution. I am aiming at some API/Jar/Code tutorial whereby I can create "ttf" files from the various image format files "png, svg, drawable,etc". I am looking to have some something whereby user can create ttf's on the fly to be used to display on UI screen textbox.

After some research found some browser based support but more interested in code based tutorial, jar anything you guys can provide would be highly appreciated.

Comment: TTFs are vectors (and not simple ones either).  You can't use PNGs.

Comment: Any other format that we can use through code that can create on the fly ttfs?

Comment: look at this tool:[FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US), it is open sourced, you can learn how they do something simular

Comment: This looks very helpful: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=143
If you follow this process in reverse, you could construct a .ttf file from a list of points. (The points may be extracted from an SVG, for example)